# Why do I can't access to non-private member of anonymous object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, access-modifiers, anonymous-class, anonymous-objects

I am a java developer and now I am learning Kotlin.

I've met an interesting(working) piece of code:

```
class C {
    private fun getObject() = object {
        val x: String = "x"
    }

    fun printX() {
        println(getObject().x)
    }
}
```

But if I remove `private` modifier for `getObject` method:

```
class C {
    fun getObject() = object {
        val x: String = "x"
    }

    fun printX() {
        println(getObject().x)
    }
}
```

The Kotlin complains

```
Unresolved reference: x
```

Could you please explain why is it done this way ? From my point of view it looks a bit weird.

Comment: My guess is that it forces the developer to be explicit about the return type when the function is public. By the way, the behaviour is defined in the docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#using-anonymous-objects-as-return-and-value-types

Comment: Another reason (which is probably the main reason when I think about it), is that public functions can be called externally (like from an application if you're programming a library), and there would be no way to type check such a call because the anonymous type (a non-nominal type) cannot be represented in the byte code. It can only be represented within the Kotlin compiler while compiling a single compilation unit. And that is guaranteed when the function is private.

Comment: @marstran I don't think what you wrote, that " the anonymous type (a non-nominal type) cannot be represented in the byte code", is right: Looking at the bytecode, it creates a public final class C$getObject$1 and a public getter method "getX()". Perhaps it's a deliberate decision to disallow it, so that the creator of the anonymous object can change its contents without having to worry about backward compatibility.

Comment: Aha, thanks for checking @k314159

Comment: Maybe something to do with subclasses being able to overwrite public methods, although that shouldn't matter when it's not defined `open` anyway

Comment: Even after years of use I'm still amazed at how smart the Kotlin compiler is. You could never do something like this in plain Java.

Comment: Perhaps we need to add Kotlin to the list of languages supporting anonymous types at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_type

Answer (score 2):

**Why it doesn't work?**

This is because we created an anonymous object/class, so it doesn't have a representation in the type system available to the user. There is no class with `x` property, we can only represent this object as `Any`. Of course, internally the compiler creates a class with `x`, but this class is not visible to us, we can't store such object with its real type in a property, etc.

**So why it does work?**

Kotlin and some other languages sometimes provide "superpowers" for local code. There are multiple examples of this:

- Kotlin: as above, access `object` members, but only if private.
- Kotlin: smart cast of properties, but only if in a local module.
- Java: type inference, but only for local vars.
- Kotlin/Java: intersection types, but only for local vars.
- Kotlin/Java: access private fields of nested/outer classes.

It's hard to provide a simple answer on why we do this. But generally, when we work on local or private code, then we focus on this small fragment of functionality which we consider implementation details of the file or class. Then we often prefer convenience and to be implicit, than keeping the code strict and explicit. If we have to change anything, we do this in a single place.

It is the opposite if components are public. In that case they could be used from tens of places around the code, we can't remember about all of them, so it is safer and easier to maintain if we keep our code more strict, so e.g. create a regular, named class instead of anonymous one.

It is even worse if accessing the code from another module. In that case the compiler doesn't know the full context of the original code, it only sees a method returning a class with some random name. Kotlin could add extra info in the bytecode by using annotations, but Java/JavaScript would ignore them entirely. Also, as we didn't provide a name for the anonymous class, compiler had to auto-generate it. If it'll generate a different name in the future, that will be a binary-incompatible change.

Another potential reason is the complexity for the compiler. To allow such features, the compiler has to keep additional metadata about the code and it has to apply some tricks to "break the rules". If they are allowed only locally, the compiler can do these complex transformations for a single file/class/module at a time, but keep a simpler code representation in general.